# SQL - Count records & update multiple columns depending on value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables ... accounts & tax. In table tax I would like to updated records (?) depending on column category available in table accounts like this:

table 'accounts'

```
id|cat2|cat3
1|A|Active
2|A|Active
3|A|Inactive
4|A|Active
5|B|Inactive
6|B|Active
```

table 'tax'

```
id|category|count_total|count_active|count_inactive
1|A|?|?|?
2|B|?|?|?
```

Desired result:

```
id|category|count_total|count_active|count_inactive
1|A|4|3|1
2|B|2|1|1
```

For count_total I tried this:

```
UPDATE tax t2,
(   SELECT count(*) 
    FROM accounts 
) t1
SET t2.count_total = t1.count(*)
WHERE t1.cat2 = t2.category;
```

Comment: I guess the column names of accounts are wrong?

Comment: I dn't see it. I get a #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) WHERE t1.cat2 = t2.category' at line 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join to update your tax table

```
UPDATE tax t2 
JOIN (
    SELECT 
    cat2,
    COUNT(*) cnt,
    SUM(cat3 = 'Active') count_active,
    SUM(cat3 = 'Inactive') count_inactive
    FROM
    accounts 
    GROUP BY cat2
) t1 
ON t1.cat2 = t2.category 
SET t2.count_total = t1.cnt ,
    t2.count_active = t1.count_active,
    t2.count_inactive = t1.count_inactive
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/WRD84437)

Answer (score 2):

Another version without `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE tax 
    SET 
    count_total = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM accounts 
        WHERE accounts.cat2 = tax.category 
    ),
    count_active = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM accounts 
        WHERE accounts.cat2 = tax.category AND accounts.cat3 = 'Active'
    ),
    count_inactive = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM accounts 
        WHERE accounts.cat2 = tax.category AND accounts.cat3 = 'Inactive'
    );
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/IOK9303)**